# Set max file size PHP

Tags: php, wamp

I am creating a social site and I am trying to limit the size of the file the user can upload. I already know about changing the `upload_max_filesize` in the wamp/xamp settings, but is there a way to do it manually ? For e.g. the settings max is 8mb but can I manually set it to 7.5mb or something in the PHP file itself ? This is how I have tried to far :

```
$file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'];
$maxsize = 1048576;

if($_FILES['files']['size'] > $maxsize) {

    $errors = "Your file is to large";
}
```

I also replaced `$_FILES['files']['size']` with `$file_size`. And I also tried:

```
if ($file_size > 15097152) {

    $errors = 'File cannot be larger than 1MB';
}
```

Thank you.

EDIT

---

```
<input name="files[]" id='files' accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

---

```
$date_time = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');
$img_limit = 10;
$maxsize = 3367463;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $errors = [];
    $file_name = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
    $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'];
    
    //$file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'];
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (strtolower($imageFileType) != "jpeg"&& strtolower($imageFileType) != "jpg" && 
        strtolower($imageFileType) != "png" && strtolower($imageFileType) != "gif") {

        $errors = "File type not allowed.";
    }

    if($_FILES['files']['size'] >= $maxsize) {

        $errors = "Your file is to large";
    }

    if ($img_limit > 10) {

        $errors = 'Cannot upload more than 10 images';
    }
    // Loop through each file
    for( $i=0 ; $i < $file_name ; $i++ ) {

        //Get the temp file path
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];

        //Make sure we have a file path
        if (!$errors || $file_tmp != "") {

            $picToUpload = $date_time . " -#- " . md5($file_name) . " -#- " . $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $uploadPicture = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "uploads/" . $picToUpload);

            $file_path = "uploads/" . $picToUpload;

            $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO images (image) VALUES (?)");
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $file_path);
            $stmt->execute();
            //$stmt->close();
            header('Location: index4.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
}

$_SESSION['error'] = '<b><p style="color: #000; font-size: 30px; top: 34%;right: 50%;position: absolute;">
' . $errors . '</p></b>';
header('Location: index4.php');
exit();
```

Comment: So what happened when you tried that, exactly? By the time you set your `$maxsize` it's pretty much already too late - the upload (or attempted upload) has already happened. Your idea would only help if `$maxsize` is always lower than `upload_max_filesize`.

Comment: What is the value of $file_size? Debug it with output in else statement.

Comment: @ADyson the only thing that happens is that the file get's uploaded successfully. I tried putting the `$maxsize` outside the `isset` function but still the same result

Comment: @NikolayShindarov I upload the file on my index3.php page and then the form get's submitted to index4.php so I don't see the value of the `$file_size` but the size of the image is 3.1mb

Comment: You need to verify what `$_FILES['files']['size']` contains when you upload this file. Either var_dump it, or log it to s file. Also I can't see what you do with $errors later or whether setting that value actually gets used to prevent the file being saved or not.

Comment: @ADyson This is what I get when I `var_dump` it `array (size=1)
  0 => int 3367463`

Comment: Ok so it's an array. Does your form have a "multiple" upload box by any chance? In that scenario you'd find the size of the first uploaded file in `$_FILES['files']['size'][0]`. But...consider looping so you can check the size of every file which might be uploaded.

Comment: @ADyson Lol yeah I didn't wanna show the whole file to clog up the question but i'll show it to give everyone a better understanding.

Comment: @ADyson just updated

Comment: How is `pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` supposed to work? `$file_name` isn't a filename, it's the number of files that were uploaded (the variable name is very confusing).

Comment: It seems like you may have changed from a single file upload to multiple files, but you didn't move all the validation checks into the loop.

Comment: @Barmar so would this be better ? `$file_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];` `$tmp = explode('.',$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
   $file_ext = strtolower(end ($tmp));

   $extensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "gif");
 
   if(in_array($file_ext, $extensions) === false){

    $errors = "Only jpeg, jpg, png and gif files are allowed.";
   }`

Comment: No. `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']` is an array, you need to loop over it. See the part of your code with the comment `// loop through each file`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231436/discussion-between-barmar-and-user13477176).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the validation checks inside the `for` loop that processes each file.

ALso, your limit on the number of images is wrong. You need to compare the number of files that were uploaded to `$img_limit`, not compare `$img_limit` to the same value you initialized it with.

I've taken the redirect and exit out of the loop, because that will redirect after uploading the first file. I've also taken `prepare` and `bind_param` out of the loop, since the same prepared statement can be used for each file.

```
$date_time = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');
$img_limit = 10;
$maxsize = 3367463;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $errors = '';
    $file_count = count($_FILES['files']['name']);

    if ($file_count > $img_limit) {
        $errors = 'Cannot upload more than 10 images';
    }
    if (!$errors) {
        $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO images (image) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $file_path);
        // Loop through each file
        for( $i=0 ; $i < $file_count ; $i++ ) {
            $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            if ($file_size >= $maxsize) {
                $errors = "Your file is too large";
            } elseif ($imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "jpg" && 
                      $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "gif") {
                $errors = "File type not allowed.";
            }
            //Make sure we have a file path
            if (!$errors && $file_tmp != "") {

                $picToUpload = $date_time . " -#- " . md5($file_name) . " -#- " . $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
                $uploadPicture = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "uploads/" . $picToUpload);

                $file_path = "uploads/" . $picToUpload;
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
if ($errors) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = '<b><p style="color: #000; font-size: 30px; top: 34%;right: 50%;position: absolute;">
' . $errors . '</p></b>';
}
header('Location: index4.php');
exit();
```

Comment: The same thing still happens. The picture gets uploaded

Comment: Is the picture bigger than 3 MB?

Comment: My code limits the size of each image. Are you trying to limit the combined size of all of them?

Comment: You can use `array_sum($_FILES['files']['size'])` to get the total size.

Comment: This will redirect and exit after saving the first file (assuming there are no errors)...

Comment: @Barmar Yeah the size of the file is 3367463

Comment: It shows the error message your file is too large, but it still gets uploaded

Comment: `||` should be `&&` in the `if` condition.

Comment: Another thing. Sometimes the error message `$errors = "Cannot upload more than 10 images";` shows up when I try to upload more than 10 images but other times it doesn't. The files don't upload though but the message just doesn't show all the time

Comment: Is this a safe way to do it ? it works this way:

Comment: `if (count($_FILES['files']['name']) >= $img_limit) {

            $errors = "Cannot upload more than 10 images";
        }`

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but my `if ($file_count > $img_limit)` edit got reverted. I've put it back in.

Comment: No I have just one file input `<input name="files[]" id='files' ...`

Comment: You had `if ($img_limit > 10)` instead of `if ($file_count > $img_limit)`

Comment: Wow that's really bizarre. Yeah I saw that above in your answer and I changed it to `if ($file_count > $img_limit)` and it didn't work. I even lowered the number. But thanks again lol

Comment: I can't explain it then. What does `var_dump($file_count);` show, and why is it different from `count($_FILES['files']['name'])`?

Comment: I know how it happened. When I was moving the `header(); exit;` out of the loop I was doing it in my editor with an older version of the answer.